# Issues over a real sum that turns out to be complex.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation, computational-mathematics

I'm having some troubles in understanding why a REAL sum turns out to be COMPLEX.

The sum in question is the following:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{k+1} b(k) \omega^{-k/4} \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{8}\right)$$

Where

$$b(k) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+4}{4}\right)\left(\frac{k+3}{4}\right)}$$

Now, as you might see, nothing complex or imaginary occurs, also because I'm studying the case

$$\boxed{\omega >0}$$

Since $k$ runs around naturals, and $b(k)$ is a ratio between positive reals, and the sine function cannot get complex or imaginary for those values of $k$, how is possible that the sum turns up to be complex?

I used W. Mathematica (serious version, not Alpha) and **one of the terms** (writing down it all would be a hell) is the following:

$$-\frac{2 \color{red}{(-1)^{3/8}} \left(\color{red}{\sqrt[4]{-1}}-1\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{5}{8},\frac{9}{8};-\frac{1}{\omega ^2}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{\omega } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$

How do those RED terms come out?

Thank you in advance

Comment: They originate from whatever algorithm Mathematica uses. Probably the terms involved are $$e^{3\pi i/8}\bigl(e^{\pi i/4} - 1\bigr) = e^{\pi i/2}\bigl(e^{\pi i/8} - e^{-\pi i/8}\bigr) = -2\sin \frac{\pi}{8}.$$

Comment: It's not because a complex number appears in the formula the result is complex. Example: $(1-i)(1+i)=1-i^2=2$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 where is the complex number in the formula? Unless you treat any real number N as N + i0. But it doesn't help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because an expression has complex numbers in it, doesn't mean it's actually complex. 
Expanding out gives
$$ (-1)^{3/8}(\sqrt[4]{-1}-1) = (-1)^{5/8}-(-1)^{3/8} = e^{5\pi i/8} - e^{3\pi i/8} \\
= e^{\pi i/2} (e^{i\pi/8}-e^{-i\pi/8}) = i \cdot 2i\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)} = -2\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)}. $$
This is real, of course; one finds using the half-angle formulae that
$$ \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{(\pi/4)}}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}. $$
(And in case you're wondering, Mathematica agrees if you use `ExpToTrig[Expand[]]` on it.)

Comment: Ah you're definitely right. My bad this time. I wonder why Mathematica does that...

Comment: It might be computationally advantageous in some way (read: it's lazy).